# Is there are postfix setting to disable prepending a sender path in the Received: header?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

Currenty emails are sent/received as :

```
Received: from localhost.localdomain (sender.host [xx.xx.xx.xx])
    by smtp.host (Postfix) with ESMTP id 7F6CC67897
    for <mail@example.com>; Thu, 19 Jan 2012 23:31:12 +0100 (CET)
```

I would like to send emails without sender location (first line) :

```
Received: by smtp.host (Postfix) with ESMTP id 7F6CC67897
    for <mail@example.com>; Thu, 19 Jan 2012 23:31:12 +0100 (CET)
```

I know I can do that with [header_check](http://posluns.com/guides/header-removal/), but this is regular expression, and performance will suffer...

Is there and postix setup variable for this? Just to ignore sender location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a valid Received: line - the source must be present.

You could use header_checks to *replace* the internal information with a static text, but the Received: line should remain standards-compliant.

Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I want to change that, because i don't want to tell who the sender is, and it is ugly (Received: from localhost.localdomain)...
I don't want to use header_checks because it is performance impact.

Comment: You can't "not tell who the sender is" - email is validated on both ends. Why do you think header-checks will impact performance ? What kind of volume do you have ?

Comment: Why is sender not SMTP server who sends emails (2 part), and not my local computer (1 part). Header_checks impacts performance because it uses regular expression on every mail. Volume is 120k+ daily

Comment: If this isn't possible like i wanted or. even recomended, they can you tell me to set host "localhost.localdomain" ? Tnx

Comment: You won't see any impact from using regexes in header_checks with such a volume - that's less than 100 messages per minute.

Comment: My mails go out 4 per second (signed by dkim). How to change hostname without headers_check? Where does postifx gets this host from?

Comment: The Received: header is filled with the value of $myhostname and the receiving connection's IP address